# eslintrc rules not being followed in react code

Tags: reactjs, eslintrc

I’m getting an error when I run my react app that "shouldn't" be.

This is a fresh instance of ‘create-react-app’ and a single component being used.
I've installed eslint and prettier locally and gotten them all set up.

The error is:

“
Compiled with problems:
ERROR
src/components/Header.js
Line 4:9: 'name' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
Line 8:17: 'x' is not defined no-undef Search for the

“

The only solution I’ve found (Aside from commenting out the offending code) is to put “no-unused-vars” and “no-undef” into the rules of the .eslintrc file and turn them off.
(I would like for eslint to warn me when either of these are triggered, but setting them to warn didn’t work either)

I’ve done that, and it still throws the error…

Component code:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  const name = 'Blaze';
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world!!!</h1>
      <h3>I am {x ? 'yes' : 'no'}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Eslint rules:
(This in inside the workspace, not the global settings)

```js
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
         "no-unused-vars": "off",
         "no-undef": "off"
    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: So what you want to do is not to fix the code issues but just to "silent" the eslint errors?

Comment: That is the goal. I don't mind warning errors, it helps keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

> Line 4:9: 'name' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

As the warning states, `name` is never used.

> Line 8:17: 'x' is not defined

You used `x` in your JSX but never defined it.

See the updated code below with an example illustrating how the warning and error might be addressed.

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  // Before, we only declared 'name'. Now, we use it in the
  // h1 in your JSX below - My name is {name}
  const name = 'Blaze';
  // Before, we used 'x' in the JSX in the h3 as the
  // the first operand in your ternary statement, but we 
  // never defined it. Now we initialize 'x' to true.
  const x = true;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world!!! My name is {name}!</h1>
      <h3>I am {x ? 'yes' : 'no'}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app creates a `eslintConfig` section in your `package.json` where you can override the default eslint configuration by adding a `overrides` subsection like this (note the `files` section is required):

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.js?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "no-unused-vars": "warn",
          "no-undef": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```